# Using specified data Jquery ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending post data to saveworld.php and getting some result in that page and I 
want to use that data in the present page .My problem is I am getting the entire DOM 
of saveworld.php.But I need only some specific text in a div having an id as linkid

this is my code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveworld.php",
    data: worldData,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            $('#space').append("<a id='" + data + "' class='square' style='background-color:#" + color2 + ";color:#" + tcolor2 + ";' href='worlds/" + data + "'>" + name2 + "</a>")
        }
    }
});​
```

i want a specific data for example I want the following data which was present in saveworld.php

```
<div id='linkid'>23</div>
```

I suppose it will be something like  `($('#linkid',data))` to get that data but I am getting  `[Object Object ]`  using that 
But I want to use the specific part of the data of the response page  saveworld.php

Comment: Why not modify saveworld.php so that it only outputs exactly what you want? Or, if that's not possible, create another page that is specifically meant to handle Ajax requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your php script return a piece of JSON code, you have to decode your JSON like that :

```
var res = $.parseJSON(data);
```

And after you can use your data as you rendered your table on your PHP script :

```
res.MyFirstVar;
```

The better way to your php script is to test if your piece of code was executed well.
You render a php table with a bool for the execution check test:

```
$result = array();
$result['ok'] = false;
/* do something */
if( //all is ok )
{
$result['ok'] = true;
}
render_json($result); //choose your way to render the json
```

on your js code, it will look like :

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "saveworld.php",
data: worldData,
success: function(data){
var res = $.parseJSON(data);
 if (res .ok){ 

$('#space').append(
    "<a id='" + res.linkid + "' class='square' style='background-color:#"+ color2 +  ";color:#" + tcolor2 + ";' href='worlds/" + res.linkid + "'>"   
     + res.name2 + "</a>"
)
}else{
//notify the use that failled
}
```